# Summarize Amount with 2 matching data

Tags: excel

i have a excel table like the following:

| Amount | Debit | Credit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 153100 | 279000 |
| 100 | 153100 | 251100 |
| 150 | 153100 | 279000 |
| 20 | 155100 | 279000 |

At the end i need a sum of this table like:

650 - 153100 to 279000

100 - 153100 to 251100

20 - 155100 to 279000

For every Debit i want the sum the matching Credit columns. (In this example 500 + 150 are sumarized because both come from 153100 and go to 279000)

Can i do this in excel (without VBA)?

Comment: Are you ok to use a pivot table?  Also, what version of Excel are you on?

Comment: Never did pivot before, tell me more :) It is Excel 2019

Comment: Have updated my answer with some information.  Without creating a tutorial, hopefully that gets you over the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pivot table to get the result you need (*without going into the construction of the pivot table*) ...

[image: Pivot Table]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Specific options on your pivot table need to be ...

1. Right click on each field and go to `Field Settings...`, go to the `Layout & Print` tab and check the box labelled `Repeat item labels`
2. Select a cell within the pivot table and go to the `Design` tab in the ribbon and select `Report Layout` -> `Show in Tabular Form`
3. You'll also want to turn off your subtotalling for the `Debit` and `Credit` columns by right clicking and unselecting the subtotal option directly within the context menu.

Just make sure you drop in the rows/columns/value like shown in my screenshot.

If you have Excel 365, you can use a combination of the `UNIQUE` function with `SUMIFS` ...

Cell **E1** = `=UNIQUE(B1:C5)`

Cell **G2** = `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,E2,C:C,F2)` (Fill Down and I've been lazy on the bounds of the lookup, I just selected the entire column because it was easier to demonstrate)

[image: UNIQUE]

[image: SUMIFS]

There's always someone smarter than me out there that will likely come up with a better solution but either of those options should work for you.